# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Number? What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var array =
            [1, 2, 3],
            [4, 5, 6],
            [7, 8, 9];
        for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            array[i] *= 2;
        }
        for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            document.write(array[i] + "<br/>");
        }
```

Here I am getting an:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Number on the middle row of my array

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you mean `array` to be an array of arrays? If yes, where's the outer array, if no, why are there three array literals?

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array of arrays, the upper array must also be designated as such:

```
var array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
```